# What are these brown and white patches on my jelly bean succulent / sedum rubrotinctum?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, succulents

I recently bought this jelly bean succulent but I didn't notice these brown and white spots.
[image: white spots]

[image: brown spots]

I really should've check the plant, but I just love succulents and I was too excited. Seems like the white spots weren't mealybugs. What are these and should I take the leaves off, cut the parts that don't have these or is there a way to solve this?

I'm very new to this so any help would be appreciated!